# What is the current proper procedure to setup a new robotic arm in MoveIt2?

Tags: ros, ros2, moveit-setup-assistant

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have good experience with ROS1 and MoveIt and now I am porting all my work into ROS2, Although the porting progress from moveit to moveit2 is now 95%, Unfortunately I figured out that the movit_setup_assistant is not yet available in ROS2 and moveit2. Thus, what is the proper way to setup a new robotic arm for moveit2?
Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/379474/what-is-the-current-proper-procedure-to-setup-a-new-robotic-arm-in-moveit2?/) by [Afif Swaidan](https://answers.ros.org/users/59252/afif-swaidan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2021-06-03

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That's very unfortunate, I would recommend you looking at [run_move_group](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/tree/main/moveit_demo_nodes/run_move_group) to see how to launch the move group node + RViz2 & [panda_moveit_config](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_resources/tree/ros2/panda_moveit_config) to see how the config files have changed, let me know if I can help you more

---

Originally posted by [jafar_abdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25259/jafar_abdi/) with karma: 221 on 2021-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Afif Swaidan](https://answers.ros.org/users/59252/afif-swaidan/) on 2021-07-01**:
Hello, thanks for replying!
So what is the way that you recommend to setup a new robot on moveit2?, use setup assistant in moveit and then modify the config files to match the ros2 and moveit2 requirments? or is there a better/cleaner/faster way to setup a new robot arm on moveit2?
Thank you!

**Comment by [jafar_abdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25259/jafar_abdi/) on 2021-07-01**:\

> use setup assistant in moveit and then modify the config files to match the ros2 and moveit2 requirments?

Yes, exactly, this's what I would recommend you to do, we're planning to port moveit setup assistant soon

**Comment by [Afif Swaidan](https://answers.ros.org/users/59252/afif-swaidan/) on 2021-07-01**:
Aha alright I got your point!
Actually I don't mind to contribute to the porting process. if you want we can get more in touch since I already tried few stuff on the setup assistant source code directly.

**Comment by [jafar_abdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25259/jafar_abdi/) on 2021-07-02**:\

> I don't mind to contribute to the porting process.

That would be great, do you mind opening an issue here https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/issues about contributing to the port, I'll add you to the weekly moveit2 stand-up so we can coordinate the port togather

**Comment by [Afif Swaidan](https://answers.ros.org/users/59252/afif-swaidan/) on 2021-07-08**:
Okay sure, I'm on it!
Thanks!